# why returned flow in room is collecting for each of my SELECT after any changes in database(INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE) MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

I am using flow to get data after any changes in my room database ,my app is note and it use SELECT by searching and filter by priority [High,Normal,Low]. and it has delete and update and insert too. I get flows from model and in viewModel by search and filter I Collect my data from flows and post it to my single liveData and in the last I get them in my Observer in the view
my problem is after in SELECT when I use UPDATE or INSERTT or DELETE , all of my old SELECT(search and filter) repeat in the moment. it means if I search 1000 once, and use filter to my notes 99 once; I will collect 1099 flows in the moment again and my observer in the my view will be bombing!!!

My Dao:

```
@Dao
interface NoteDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun saveNote(entity : NoteEntity)
    
    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteNote(note : NoteEntity)
    
    @Update
    suspend fun updateNote(note : NoteEntity)
    
    @Query("SELECT * FROM $NOTE_TABLE")
    fun getAllNotes() : Flow<MutableList<NoteEntity>>
    
    @Query("SELECT * FROM $NOTE_TABLE WHERE id == :id")
    fun getNote(id : Int) : Flow<NoteEntity>
    
    @Query("SELECT * FROM $NOTE_TABLE WHERE priority == :priority")
    fun fileNote(priority : String) : Flow<MutableList<NoteEntity>>
    
    @Query("SELECT * FROM $NOTE_TABLE WHERE title LIKE '%' || :title || '%'")
    fun searchNote(title : String) : Flow<MutableList<NoteEntity>>

}
```

My Repository:

```
class MainRepository @Inject constructor(private val dao : NoteDao) {
fun getAllNotes() = dao.getAllNotes()
fun getNotesByPriority(priority : String) = dao.fileNote(priority)
fun getNotesBySearch(title : String) = dao.searchNote(title)
suspend fun deleteNote(note: NoteEntity) = dao.deleteNote(note)
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: MainRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val notesData = object : MutableLiveData<DataStatus<MutableList<NoteEntity>>>(){
        override fun postValue(value: DataStatus<MutableList<NoteEntity>>?) {
            super.postValue(value)
            Log.e("TAGJH", "postValue: ${value?.data?.size}")
        }
    }
    
    fun getAllNotes() = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.getAllNotes().collect {
            Log.e("TAGJH", "getAll: ${it.size}")
            notesData.postValue(DataStatus.success(it, it.isEmpty()))
        }
    }
    
    fun getNoteByPriority(priority: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.getNotesByPriority(priority).collect {
            Log.e("TAGJH", "priority ${it.size }->$priority")
            notesData.postValue(DataStatus.success(it, it.isEmpty()))
        }
    }
    
    fun getNoteBySearch(characters: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.getNotesBySearch(characters).collect {
            Log.e("TAGJH", "collect: ${it.size}")
            notesData.postValue(DataStatus.success(it, it.isEmpty()))
        }
    }
    
    fun deleteNote(note: NoteEntity) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.deleteNote(note)
    }

}
```

My View:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var selectedItem: Int = 0
    private var _binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding
    
    @Inject
    lateinit var noteAdapter: NoteAdapter
    
    @Inject
    lateinit var noteEntity: NoteEntity
    
    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        _binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding?.root)
    
        binding?.apply {
            setSupportActionBar(notesToolbar)
            addNoteBtn.setOnClickListener {
                NoteFragment().show(supportFragmentManager, NoteFragment().tag)
            }
    
            viewModel.notesData.observe(this@MainActivity) {
    
                showEmpty(it.isEmpty)
    
                noteAdapter.setData(it.data!!)
                noteList.apply {
                    layoutManager =
                        StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
                    adapter = noteAdapter
                }
            }
    
            viewModel.getAllNotes()
    
            notesToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
                when (it.itemId) {
                    R.id.actionFilter -> {
                        filterByProperty()
                        return@setOnMenuItemClickListener true
                    }
                    else -> return@setOnMenuItemClickListener false
                }
            }
    
            deleteAndUpdateListener()
    
        }
    }
    
    private fun deleteAndUpdateListener() =
        noteAdapter.onItemClickListener { note, title ->
            when (title) {
    
                DELETE -> {
                    noteEntity.id = note.id
                    noteEntity.title = note.title
                    noteEntity.des = note.des
                    noteEntity.priority = note.priority
                    noteEntity.category = note.category
                    viewModel.deleteNote(noteEntity)
                }
                EDIT -> {
                    val noteFragment = NoteFragment()
                    val bundle = Bundle()
                    bundle.putInt(BUNDLE_ID, note.id)
                    noteFragment.arguments = bundle
                    noteFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, NoteFragment().tag)
                }
            }
    
        }
    
    
    private fun showEmpty(isShown: Boolean) {
        binding?.apply {
            if (isShown) {
                emptyShowing.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                noteList.visibility = View.GONE
            } else {
                emptyShowing.visibility = View.GONE
                noteList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
    }
    
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _binding = null
    }
    
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar, menu)
        val search = menu.findItem(R.id.actionSearch)
        val searchView = search.actionView as SearchView
        searchView.queryHint = getString(R.string.search)
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }
    
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                viewModel.getNoteBySearch(newText)
                Log.e("TAGJH", "searching")
                return true
            }
        })
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
    
    private fun filterByProperty() {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val priories = arrayOf(ALL, HIGH, NORMAL, LOW)
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(priories, selectedItem) { dialog, item ->
            when (item) {
                0 -> {
                    viewModel.getAllNotes()
                }
                in 1..3 -> {
                    viewModel.getNoteByPriority(priories[item])
                }
            }
    
            selectedItem = item
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
    
        val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()
    }

}
```

I want to see my note after any update or delete or insert is updating in my last SELECT from room database

Comment: What is the meaning: @Query("SELECT * FROM $NOTE_TABLE WHERE title LIKE '%' || :title || '%'"?

Comment: it uses for sesrch in note based on titles, for example "e" is exsisted in «ear»,«learn»  and etc...

Comment: @Maziyar I am facing the same problem, did you figure out the solution?

Comment: yes but it is expensive.  i shared the solution in my github as a project https://github.com/maziar-ghanbari/NoteDesk